# convert xml to json after retrieving records from db using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml

I have to convert `xml response to json` in `angularjs`. I am using an Rest api which provide response in xml format but angularjs needs json response when retrieving through $http.get().

Below is how i am using rest api in angularjs.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

$http({
 method: 'GET',
 url: "https://some-url?fieldList=field1,field2"
}).then(function(response) {
        $scope.obj=response.data.records;},function(response){});}
});
</scripts>
```

how to convert xml response to json and to provide it as an input to some variable $scope.obj?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this,
I used the function given on this page https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
}
 };
xhttp.open("GET", "your.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlToJson(xmlDoc);
}
function xmlToJson(xml) {

// Create the return object
var obj = {};

if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
    // do attributes
    if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
    obj["@attributes"] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
            var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
            obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        }
    }
} else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
    obj = xml.nodeValue;
}

// do children
if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
    for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
        var nodeName = item.nodeName;
        if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
            obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
        } else {
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                var old = obj[nodeName];
                obj[nodeName] = [];
                obj[nodeName].push(old);
            }
            obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
        }
    }
}
return obj;
};
```